# I'm getting following error - NPM ERROR : debug module is not working

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, xdebug

I need to use `debug` module to replace my `console.log` in my node application. I've installed the `debug` module in my application using following command.

```
npm install debug
```

Then I've initialized the `debug` variable as described below.

```
const debug = require('debug')('http');
debug('debug information');
```

but nothing is getting logged in terminal. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Don't forget to set the DEBUG env variable with a list of debug functions, below an example within the interpreter

```
~  DEBUG=http node
> var debug = require('debug')('http')
undefined
> debug('Test debug log')
 http Test debug log +0ms
undefined
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Aitor, where should I set the DEBUG env variable. when running node application or inside my source code.

Comment: When running "DEBUG=http node app.js"

Answer (score 1):

On Windows

```
set DEBUG=*,-< module_name_not_to_include >
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm listing the method from scratch for better understanding

Step 1 : install npm debug package

```
npm i debug
```

Step 2: Import that package to the file, for example we've main file `index.js`

```
const debug = require('debug')('app:run')
```

then i'm creating an async function `run` as mentioned

```
async function run() {
    app.listen(4000, () => {
        debug(`app listening on port 4000`)
    })
}

run()
```

then last step is to run the code by following command and it'll show all the activities getting logged into your app.

```
DEBUG=app* node index.js
```

you can explore other activities by following command

```
DEBUG=* node index.js
```